# Change text back to default on submit button

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit, submit-button

so I can change the text on the submit button after submission. Like from 'Send message' it will become 'Sent' after submission. Is it possible to return the text back to 'Send message' after a few seconds? The form is processed in AJAX.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that you have a form that has an id called `ajax-form`, an input field in that form has an id: `form-input` and a name: `title`, and a submit button whose id is `submit-btn`. Now, let's do the ajax as blow:

```
var ajaxForm   = $('#ajax-form'),
    submitBtn  = ajaxForm.find('#submit-btn');
ajaxForm.on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxForm.prop('action'),
    data: {
      title: ajaxForm.find('input').val()
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
      submitBtn.text('Send message');
    },
    success: function() {
      submitBtn.text('Sent');
    },
    complete: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        submitBtn.text('Send message'); // Change it back after 4 seconds
      }, 4000);
    }
  });
});
```

You might need to add the error handler. For more information please see the jQuery AJAX docs:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Hoping this can help you. :)